# 4 maths books and 8 English books

Tags: combinatorics

There are 12 different books, 4are  maths books and 8 are English books. How many arrangements can there be so that the maths books are separated?

I got $\dbinom84*4!*4!*8!*2$ which doesn't give the answer. I do not know what is missing.

MEMEMEMEEEEE
That was my 1st arrangement, i grouped 4 english books with 4 of the maths book so that they are seperated but since you have 8 english books, you need to pick any 4 , so 8C4 * 4! . Now you have group 1 english book with a maths book , the number of items are reduced to 8 rather than 12 which i got 8!. Also you can arrange the maths books differently which gives 4!. 
Now there is another way to group them, which is EMEMEMEMEEEE , that is why i multiplied by 2.
Thats how i got the the above calculation but it doesnt give me the answer provided by 12!-(4!*9!)

The indirect method will be $12!-(4!*9!)$ but I want to have the direct one.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you distinguish between the math books (and between the english books) or do you only care about the math-english ordering?

Comment: All 12 books are different except that 4 of them r maths and 8 english

Comment: Please use the edit button at the bottom of your post to clarify that the books are all distinct rather than putting that information in the comments, where it might be missed.  Also, since the order matters, the tag permutations would be more appropriate.  You may also want to use the tag combinatorics.

Comment: Please justify your answer with a reasoning, maybe we can find a flaw.

Comment: MEMMM counts as seperated.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to interpret as: how many arrangements without all four math books together.

There are $12!$ arrangements.

However, there are 9 places at which a sequence of 4 math books can start which is a forbidden arrangement.

So you have to subtract $9*8!*4!$ from all arrangements: $9$ places times the arrangements of math/English books.

In the answer $9*8!$ is written as $9!$, which is obviously correct, hides that this is a combination of 9 starting positions and arranging 8 items

Comment: Yea ...it gives you 12!-(4!*9!).....but i want the direct way....

Comment: What is not direct about this?

Comment: You can also think of it as arranging nine objects, eight of which are English books and the ninth is "all the maths books". Then for each such arrangement there are $4!$ arrangements of the original set with the maths books together.

Comment: You use the whole possible arrangements and subtracted the part that you do not want ......i want to calculate the part that i want directly

Comment: @Raynezick  This is the most efficient solution to the problem.  To calculate it directly, you have to consider multiple cases: no two math books are consecutive, at most two are consecutive, two pairs, exactly three are consecutive.

Comment: @Raynezick, I think you shouldn't. This method should be in your toolset. How would you count all cards in a deck that are not the ace of spades?

Answer (score 1):

For validation $12!-9!4!=8!4!486$, so we need to account for $486$ permutations.

This is:

$$\dbinom94+\dbinom93\cdot3+\dbinom92\cdot2+\dbinom92$$

$$=126+252+72+36$$

from splitting the maths books into $1111$ (once), $112$ (thrice), $13$ (twice), $22$ (once) into the $9$ available slots between the English books.

Comment: +1! Very elegant demonstration of 'direct' solution! I think it also shows that you really need deep understanding and high accuracy to provide this answer correctly.

Comment: Yes very insightful and clear explanation. Now i know what i missed.